# In grid view row deleting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, webforms

```
    protected void grd_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        string query = "delete from details where sno='"+grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value+"'";-----(getting error like Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index)
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        filldata();
        con.Close();  
     }
```

gettnig error like Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{

```
      SqlConnection con=newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
      con.Open();
      int Sno = Convert.ToInt32(grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
      string query="delete from Details where Sno="+Sno;
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
      int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
```

}

Comment: I had to use Grid1.Rows[Grid1.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text to get it to work for me. But your post did point me the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the following statement

```
grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]
```

And means that the value of `e.RowIndex` is outside of the range of elements in the `grd.DataKeys` array.

To debug this further you'll need to find out the value of `e.RowIndex`, and see how many elements are in the `grd.DataKeys` array.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `DataKeyNames="your_id_column"` property for GridView in .aspx page

Then in `grd_RowDeleting` method you can access it by `grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value` or by `grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["your_id_column"]`

Also it's better parse result to string